# How to hide a random text with a div tag using a class on product pages with a specific tag

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, css

In all WooCommerce single product pages we have a single line of text. The text is in a div with css class "myclass".

And all products have a specific product tag e.g. "electronic".

Now if we delete the tag "electronic" manually, the single text line should disappear, should be hidden via css or a function ...

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Could you provide a link to your site and indicate what section needs this logic?

Comment: you can hide the text using css,provide the HTML code to get the solution

Comment: @Buttered_Toast

Thank you.

The site is not online yet.

Maybe a has_tag() function can be used. So if the specific tag is assigned to a WooCommerce Porduct on all single products the css class should be active. And if no tag is assigned the css class should remain inactive. Is this possible?

Comment: @KanonChowdhury Thank you. <div class"myclass">Image source: Example Shop</div>

Comment: yes @eightyn you can hide that text with css like body.tax-product_cat . myclass{display:none} / body.**tag-slug** . myclass{display:none} try this that can help you..